# Add certificate to Trusted Publisher programmatically

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, certutil

I have a usb driver which is signed. I also have the certificate provided by the publisher.
If I try to install the driver with `pnputil`

```
pnputil /add-driver CerttName.cer /install
```

I'm asked if I want to add the publisher to Trusted Publishers.

To avoid it I tried to add the certificate to Trusted Publishers programmatically

```
string file = @"C:\Certificates\CertName.cer";
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(file)));
store.Close();
```

The certificate has been added but I'm still prompted by `pnputil` to add the publisher to Trusted Publishers.

If I use `certutil`

```
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" CertName.cer
```

then I'm not prompted by `pnputil`.

I also tried to import the certificate manually from certmgr.msc but it also didn't work.

I don't understand why only `certutil` works and other ways (specially X509Store) not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are installing the certificate in `CurrentUser` store, while it must be presented in `LocalMachine` store. Certutil defaults to local machine.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Comment: If I use certutil I see the certificate in CurrentUser.

Comment: Because it is propagated from `LocalMachine`.